# Joining files in pandas

Tags: pandas

I come from an Excel background but I love pandas and it has truly made me more efficient. Unfortunately, I probably carry over some bad habits from Excel. I have three large files (between 2 million and 13 million rows each) which contain data on interactions which could be tied together, unfortunately, there is no unique key connecting the files. I am literally concatenating (Excel formula) 3 fields into one new column on all three files.

Three columns which exist on each file which I combined together (the other fields would be like the reason for interaction on one file, the score on another file, and the some other data on the third file which I would like to tie together back to a certain agentID):

```
Date | CustomerID | AgentID
```

I edit my date format to be uniform on each file:

```
df[Date] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], coerce = True)
df[Date] =  df[Date].apply(lambda x:x.date().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

Then I create a unique column (well, as unique as I can get it.. sometimes the same customer interacts with the same agent on the same date but this should be quite rare):

```
df[Unique] = df[Date].astype(str) + df[CustomerID].astype(str) + df[AgentID].astype(str)
```

I do the same steps for df2 and then:

```
combined = pd.merge(df, df2, how = 'left', on = 'Unique')
```

I typically send that to a new csv in case something crashes, gzip it, then read it again and do the same process again with the third file.

```
 final = pd.merge(combined, df2, how = 'left', on = 'Unique')
```

As you can see, this takes time. I have to format the dates on each and then turn them into text, create an object column which adds to the filesize, and (due to the raw data issues themselves) drop duplicates so I don't accidentally inflate numbers. Is there a more efficient workflow for me to follow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `on = 'Unique'`:

```
combined = pd.merge(df, df2, how = 'left', on = 'Unique')
```

you can pass a list of columns to the `on` keyword parameter:

```
combined = pd.merge(df, df2, how='left', on=['Date', 'CustomerID', 'AgentID'])
```

Pandas will correctly merge rows based on the triplet of values from the `'Date', 'CustomerID', 'AgentID'` columns. This is safer (see below) and easier than building the Unique column.

---

For example,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(2015)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': pd.to_datetime(['2000-1-1','2000-1-1','2000-1-2']),
                   'CustomerID':[1,1,2],
                   'AgentID':[10,10,11]})

df2 = df.copy()
df3 = df.copy()
L = len(df)
df['ABC'] = np.random.choice(list('ABC'), L)
df2['DEF'] = np.random.choice(list('DEF'), L)
df3['GHI'] = np.random.choice(list('GHI'), L)
df2 = df2.iloc[[0,2]]

combined = df
for x in [df2, df3]:
    combined = pd.merge(combined, x, how='left', on=['Date','CustomerID', 'AgentID'])
```

yields

```
In [200]: combined
Out[200]: 
   AgentID  CustomerID      Date ABC DEF GHI
0       10           1  2000-1-1   C   F   H
1       10           1  2000-1-1   C   F   G
2       10           1  2000-1-1   A   F   H
3       10           1  2000-1-1   A   F   G
4       11           2  2000-1-2   A   F   I
```

---

A cautionary note:

Adding the CustomerID to the AgentID to create a Unique ID could be problematic
-- particularly if neither has a fixed-width format.

For example, if `CustomerID = '12'` and `AgentID = '34'` Then (ignoring the date which causes no problem since it does have a fixed-width) `Unique` would be
`'1234'`. But if `CustomerID = '1'` and `AgentID = '234'` then `Unique` would
again equal `'1234'`. So the `Unique` IDs may be mixing entirely different
customer/agent pairs.

---

PS. It is a good idea to parse the date strings into date-like objects

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], coerce=True)
```

Note that if you use

```
combined = pd.merge(combined, x, how='left', on=['Date','CustomerID', 'AgentID'])
```

it is not necessary to convert any of the columns back to strings.

Comment: Awesome. Worked. Perfectly thanks. I went back and edited all of my joining files.